# How can I make intellisense work in Razor for classes where the namespace is imported in web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor

I've added the following to the Web.config in my ~/Views folder:

```
<add namespace="DTuppeny.Blog.Models" />
```

This means at the top of my view, I can now type:

```
@model Post
```

instead of

```
@model DTuppeny.Blog.Models.Post
```

This all compiles and works fine, however when I type "@Model." I don't get any intellisense.

Is this a bug, or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried what you describe in a project of mine, and as long as I kept the .cshtml file open, the intellisense indeed didn't work.

It did work though after I closed and re-opened the file (I also recompiled in between... not sure if that is necessary). Did you do that?

Also: Do you have [the latest tools update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=82cbd599-d29a-43e3-b78b-0f863d22811a) installed?

Comment: Weird! I rebuilt and even restarted Visual Studio, but it didn't work. So I just closed the file and re-opened, and the word "Post" was now highlighted, and the intellisense works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you modify the top level web.config, there is another web.config in the views folder